# How to get server id and channel id in discord.js using command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was trying to save guild id and channel id using one command, using lowdb but I when I'm using `var server = client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id;`  I get error that says, Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. And I don't know why.

```
var server = client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id;
var channel = client.guilds.get(message.channel.id).id;

db.get('posts')
  .push({ id: server, title: channel})
  .write();
```

There's all code I made, and I define everything on start of code

```
const client = require('<there's path but I don't want to show it cuz there's my name>/my_bot.js');
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const adapter = new FileSync('db.json')
const db = low(adapter)
```

If you know what's wrong please help

Comment: Hi, which version of discord.js are you using? You're sure that you're running that code after the [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event?

Comment: I'm using v12 discord.js I guess it can be problem of it but im not sure how to fix it and how to set it right way, I was trying to find solution in documentation but I couldn't i only found .id and how to use it but it didn't solve my problem. And yes cuz im using command handler and i have all const in file with command that's activate it, and in main file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using discord.js@v12 then you should remember that you should go through the `.cache` property for your code to work. You can check that by yourself by looking at the docs for [`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds).
Also, you don't need to get the channel and the guild from their IDs, since you already have them stored as message properties.
Here's how I would do it:

```js
let server = message.guild.id, // ID of the guild the message was sent in
  channel = message.channel.id // ID of the channel the message was sent in
```

To be fair, I wouldn't be able to explain why you get that error.

Comment: Thanks everything work good, now I just need to figure out when and how to replace data of existing "post" so it won't create new post every time someone set channel, and send welcome message to two different channels on one server

Answer (score -1):

Ok so you got "get" is not a function because in v12 it has to be client.guilds.cache.get(`whatever you wanna put here`)